# Confusion over xcworkspace file

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I am pretty new with podfiles and importing frameworks and all of that good stuff.

I'm getting a really fun error trying to use the BigBoard framework imported with cocoapods:

[image]

I know it's because I'm in my .xcodeproj file. I did a full installation of the pod

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
target ‘SwiftyStockApp’ do
use_frameworks!
  pod 'BigBoard', '~> 1.1'
end
```

and it didn't automatically generate one of those .xcworkspace files. How do I get one?

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

**EDIT**

After installing, the terminal gives a message reading: *"Abort trap: 6"*

Comment: check you have cocoa pods install in your mac or not??

Comment: please try this, open the Workspace and clean the Project & Build project Before run.

Comment: that's the problem, i'm not getting a workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have cocoa pods installed.

Go in your mac terminal and run:

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Then go into your project folder still (in the terminal) and run:

```
$ pod install
```

See: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html

Comment: I've got that, that's how I got the podfile to work with. I'm seeing in the terminal "Abort trap: 6". does that clarify anything?